# Meteor collection observe change

Tags: meteor

The following code fires a client side when a certain info is populated in a collection. sometimes it does not work on smartphone but works fine on desktop Chrome.
Is it correct to call the `find` and `findOne` on the collection? not an over kill?  thx

```
  'myMethod': function (age, health) {
    Meteor.call('doStuff-that-will-change-the-document');
    myCollection.find().observeChanges({   // <===== find
      changed: function (id, fields) {
        let newDoc = myCollection.findOne({age: age});  // <==== another findOne
        Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.user()._id}, {$unset: {'profile.taskInProgress': ''}});
        if (newDoc) {
          if (fields.filed1) {
            lib.dothis1(newDoc, health);
          } else if (fields.field2) {
            lib.dothat(newDoc, health);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

**edit**

I need the client code to fire `lib.dothis1` or `lib.dothat` when the `field1` and `field2` get updated respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch what was added, just use the `added` property - [see the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges)

> Establishes a live query that invokes callbacks when the result of the query changes. In contrast to observe, observeChanges provides only the difference between the old and new result set, not the entire contents of the document that changed.
>
> callbacks may have the following functions as properties:
>
> ```
> added(id, fields) or
> ```
>
> A new document entered the result set. It has the id and fields
>   specified. fields contains all fields of the document excluding the
>   _id field. The new document is before the document identified by before, or at the end if before is null.

Than you get a new callback when a new doc is added, which would be more efficient than using `find` again.

Comment: I went over the question again, and it's unclear how the 'age' informs a new doc, so maybe I misunderstood the question - if so let me know, and clarify what you hope to achive with `findOne`.